# How can I order the column values that appear in a Filter list in ag-Grid and AdapTable?

Tags: ag-grid

We have a user requirement that the values in a date column in our ag-Grid Trade Blotter are shown in reverse order (i.e. most recent first).

Is there an easy way to do that?

We are using ag-Grid 23 with Adaptable 7.2.5.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of doing it:

1. Easy way - set the 'sortColumnValuesInFilter' property in Filter Options to true in your Adaptable Options (see https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/adaptable-options/filter-options) and then it will display items in the filter using whatever sort the column currently has.
2. More complicated and powerful way - provide a getColumnValues implementation. This is a user function which is run whenever AdapTable needs to show distinct values in a column - so you can decide which columns to apply it and then sort the return list however you want (see https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/user-functions/get-column-values-user-function)

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518883/react-ag-grid-row-auto-height-doesnt-work